# Making a stack exchange site to discuss problems for an upcoming exam

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I have to prepare some students for their upcoming exam, and I wondered if I couldn't just create a stack exchange site where students could ask questions and other students discuss them. Only if they are stuck, I will try to help them.

The site would only have to up for about a week, after that, it could be shut down. Oh, and the questions and answers should be all german and no one "outside" should be able to help them (so that they are forced to ask and help each other).

Am I allowed to do this? And if not, are there any alternatives to Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... any alternatives to Stack Exchange?

Yes, with [Shapado](http://shapado.com/) such a site can literally be created in a few minutes (for the time being there is no charge; it might be US$9 per month in the future). It is listed on an annotated list of alternatives here on Meta Stack Overflow: *[Stack Overflow Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267)*

> no one "outside" should be able to help them

As far as I tell Shapado does not allow anonymous participation so you could keep an eye on the total number of users after all the students have registered and delete any new ones. Perhaps it is possible to turn registration on and off.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange is meant to create large, lasting communities of experts on at least somewhat broad topics. I don't think it is likely a good fit for what you are trying to do.

Assuming you work at a school or university, you could contact your IT people to see if they have a solution (for example, many schools use [Blackboard](http://www.blackboard.com/), which would work well for this).

If you really want to, you could try emailing Jeff using the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to see if he will consider your idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I allowed to do this?

No.

1. You cannot propose a private site (or get a private site made for very little $).
2. The idea of creating a site is for it to be long-term/permanent.

> And if not, are there any alternatives to Stack Exchange?

Yes, grab a copy of some unicode-enabled forum software and go to town. I'm not up on this kind of thing anymore, so I can't really suggest anything specific.

> ... no one "outside" should be able to help them (so that they are forced to ask and help each other)

Unless you're planning to run the site on your intranet and block all internet access, good luck with this.

Answer (score -1):

Propose it on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There's no way to propose private sites on area 51.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.